# Merging multiple JSONs into one: TypeError, a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, json

So, I am trying write a small program in python 3.6 to merge multiple JSON files (17k) and I am getting the above error.
I put together the script by reading other SO Q&As. I played around a little bit, getting various errors, nevertheless, I couldn't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import glob
import json
import os
import sys


def merge_json(source, target):
    os.chdir(source)
    read_files = glob.glob("*.json")
    result = []
    i = 0
    for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
        print("Files merged so far:" + str(i))
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            print("Appending file:" + f)
            result.append(json.load(infile))
        i = i + 1 

    output_folder = os.path.join(target, "mergedJSON")
    output_folder = os.path.join(output_folder)
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)
    os.chdir(output_folder)

    with open("documents.json", "wb") as outfile:
        json.dump(result, outfile)

try:
    sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
except:
    sys.exit("\n\n Error: Missing arguments!\n See usage example:\n\n  python merge_json.py {JSON source directory} {output directory} \n\n")

merge_json(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Could you specify what error are you getting ?

Comment: `various errors` is very vague

Comment: TypeError, a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you are opening the file in 'wb' mode which means it works with bytes-like objects only. But `json.dump` is trying to write a string to it. You can simply change the open mode from 'wb' to 'w' (text mode) and it will work.

Comment: Hmm, thx, I thought I tried that and dismissed it since all I got was an empty file. I should have waited longer I guess. I tried it on a more fit machine now, and it still took some time but it works.